# I do not know where the Deepmind code resides?

Tags: github

I am reading [Skilful precipitation nowcasting using deep generative models of radar](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-021-03854-z#code-availability). The code is on [Github](https://github.com/deepmind/deepmind-research/tree/master/nowcasting). As I am not familiar with Github, I am confused about where the actual code is. I see neither any file with postfixes such as .py or .cpp. Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Go to the root of the project https://github.com/deepmind/deepmind-research and press "t" to open the fuzzy file search, then type ".py". the link you have is to a readme in a specific folder in the project.

Comment: @AndyRay: Can you read my comment under Dropout's answer and tell me what you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click on the `<> code` button on the top left you can see various sub-projects.. Some of them have code and some of them don't. There are no additional branches, so I'd say that the code for those sub-projects is not pushed to the repository.

https://github.com/deepmind/deepmind-research

Comment: I did and went to https://github.com/deepmind/deepmind-research . It contains a lot of directories (folders) each of which is a project. When I click on and go into the directory /nowcasting, it goes back to https://github.com/deepmind/deepmind-research/tree/master/nowcasting. It does not contain any actual code. Does not mean, as you say, that they have not pushed the actual code into the repository?

Comment: Exactly. The code is not there for that project.. I thought it was in a different branch, but there are no alternative branches either. At least not publicly accessible.